# Should a (junior) developer try to push for better processes and practices in their development/IT team?

Tags: project-management, scrum, development-process, process, product-owner

I'm a junior developer that is given the ability to help shape my team's processes if I can justify the change, and if it helps the team get work done. This is new for me as my past companies more or less had rigidly defined processes that came from management.

My team is fairly small and somewhat new (<3 years old). They lack:

- a well defined software development/work management framework (like
  scrum)
- strong product ownership
- well defined roles ( e.g. business staff will do manual testing)
- regular standup meetings
- a consolidated issue tracking process (we have a tool, the process is still being developed)
- a unit, system, regression, or manual testing suite or list
- documentation on business logic and processes
- a knowledge base to document internal and customer facing tips

And the list goes on. Management is open to the implementation of improvements so long as the value is justified and it helps the most important work (namely the development) get done. The underlying assumption however is that you have to take ownership in the implementation, as no one is going to do it for you. And it goes without saying some of the above projects are non-trivial, without a doubt time consuming, and are clearly not development work.

Is it worth a (junior) developer's effort to try and push for the above as time goes on? Or is it best to "stay in your lane" and focus on the development, and leave the bulk of the process definition, and optimization to management?

Comment: I notice that one of your tags is Scrum. Is your team a Scrum team? And if so, are they holding retrospectives?

Comment: @Daniel They are not but they are in the process of implementing a more well defined agile development process. Scrum is on the table as one of the possible routes we will take.

Comment: Is there any reason you use "they" instead of "we"? E.g. "My team is fairly small and somewhat new (<3 years old). They lack"?

Comment: Just an FYI, if you have worked for multiple companies you're likely not a junior anymore.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle some appear to be more content with keeping things the way they are, others are open to the changes but the clear subtext is that "if you want it  you do it". So for example if I wanted us to begin using an automated regression testing suite, I would need to be the one to spearhead its development. Until this hypothetical suite was somewhat developed I could not reasonably expect anyone to use or contribute to it.

Comment: @kevin not all my job roles have been development so I would consider my general understanding of the SDLC not junior, but I am very much a junior developer. Especially compared to some of the other members of my colleagues who have 10+ years experience in development, and some specially in the technologies that we use.

Comment: What makes you think that the things you list are "better", and not just the latest time-wasting fad?  Can you make a reasonable case for each one?

Comment: _"Management is open to the implementation of improvements [..]"_, that is largely irrelevant, more important is whether or not the rest of your team is open to it. If they aren't, having management buy-in, but not team buy-in is a road to an adversarial relation with the rest of your team.

Comment: Whether its an uninformed but accurate guess or an experience influenced and reasoned offering, a good idea is a good idea. The idea of "tenure" is just about worthless in a profession that has a fairly fast moving target, and there have been so many good ideas that are lost to the Sr./Jr. nonsense.

Comment: Speaking from experience, this is a really good way to burn out if you don't have at least some buy in from the rest of your team

Comment: It's not entirely connected to your question, but I think it could be a good article for you : https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/25/getting-things-done-when-youre-only-a-grunt/

Comment: @jamesqf Well, Scrum was introduced in 1986 to address problems that were well understood in the late 1970s, and it has proven to address those problems very effectively. Not using Scrum in 1999 was behind the curve. Not using Scrum in 2019 is either incompetence or fraud.

Comment: @TKK - there are plenty of alternatives to Scrum. It's just one particular methodology that comes with a lot of unnecessary crap attached.

Comment: I'd recommend before trying to apply fixes to your teams process, that you apply a process to your process fixes. What I mean is you should rank all the list of possible improvements in two ways, how valuable they will be to the team, and how much work they will be to implement. Focus on your biggest bang for the buck, hopefully something simple for you to implement/maintain that the team and company will overwhelming recognize as a positive process improvement. Building on that goodwill will help you get more support and resources for bigger changes.

Comment: @DavorŽdralo Perhaps I should say "some form of Agile." Ancient methodologies like Waterfall, or the all too familiar complete lack of methodology like the asker describes, are utterly inexcusable in 1986+33.

Comment: "if I can justify the change"...  This!  You need to be able  to convince others it is a benefit, especially if it takes time to manifest.  A good thing to keep in mind is if somebody came and told you that using LISP could benefit everybody enormeously (or Postscript or Haskell or whatever you are most unfamiliar with), how would you react?   Especially with delivery deadlines?

Comment: Remember that the smaller the team, the fewer formal processes are needed. Some of what you find lacking is likely just overhead in a small team (standups, ownership).

Comment: @overflow831. Agile is about being pro-active and assertive team members, but mainly for what you were hired to bring to the team. It is your duty to advocate for improvements to the operation of the team, but up to the team to decide what works for them. However, you need to be aware of the personalities and dynamics of the team and so avoid making suggestions that may tend to be too disruptive. Ideally, an agile team is made up of experienced people (not juniors) who know themselves enough, and can read other people.

Comment: While I'm sure somewhere out there there's an exception to the rule, I'd say that a team with no regular standups (as OP describes them) is not a scrum team, no matter what they call themselves.

Answer (score 182):

Good answers so far, but they don't cover all the bases.

In my experience, many people fresh out of college have fantastic theoretical knowledge - far better than me or many other seniors with decades building software for a living.

BUT, and that's a big BUT, that knowledge isn't grounded in any practical scenario. In the real world, a lot of that theory falls flat, or at the very least has to be taken with a massive grain of salt as it's found in practice to not work that well in a real world scenario.

Case in point: An application I worked on a long time ago was designed by a brilliant OO theoretician, architected to follow OO principles and theory to the T, with lots of patterns applied everywhere.

It was a fantastic piece of software design.

Sadly, this resulted in production and maintenance nightmare. The code base was so large and complex that places were impossible to change; Not because it was especially brittle but because it was so complex, nobody dared touch it in fear of what would happen (the original architect/designer had been a contractor who'd long since left).

It also performed very poorly, precisely because of the multi-layered structure of patterns, and class libraries that design required.  For example, clicking a button on a screen to make a single call to the database would result in several hundred object instantiations and method calls - all in the name of ensuring loose coupling and things like that.

This architect had been a university professor with several books about the topic to his name. He'd never worked a day as a programmer on a commercial project.

People with practical experience building software would have realised what a monstrosity that design would inevitably lead to and taken a more pragmatic approach, leading to a system that's easier to maintain and performed better as well.

The same thing can apply to many other things you encounter as a fresh graduate, or indeed a new employee in any company. Don't assume that because your theoretical base tells you something is wrong or sub-optimal that there's not a very good reason for it to be done that way.

Even now, with over 20 years experience in the field, I'm wary of criticising the way things are done in companies I go to work with. I'll mention in passing that I noticed things are different than in my experience being the most optimal, but not in a belligerent way.  This often leads to interesting conversations as to why those things are as they are. Maybe changes will happen and maybe not, depending on whether the value of changing things is smaller than the cost.

Don't be afraid to suggest things may be done better, but always make sure that you don't come across as the know-it-all snot-nosed kid but rather as a coworker who's trying and willing to not just learn but also help improve processes for the betterment of the company, not just theoretical correctness.

Comment: I could not agree more with your observation. Practice is by far the best way to know what works, and even then there is always more, and other.

Comment: If a project is insanely complex, dreadful to change, then it is **not** a “fantastic piece of software design”.

Comment: This. I think the only thing to ask for a junior is **willing**. Willing for self-improvement, awareness, learning, etc. I have also to say that for many companies the word *"better"* has rarely the same meaning that it has for us (the employees). It's often translated into *"more"* or *"whatever is needed at any cost"*. Juniors need motivation and guidance to preserve the interest on the field. Not an amount of c...p wrapped up in silk and falsely labelled as *"the opportunity for your career"*. The main goal for juniors is **learning**.

Comment: This answer makes it sound like OOP is a body of knowledge that academics are obsessed with, while the industry "knows better". In my experience, it's the other way around: academics care very little about OOP, while lots of companies are still obsessed with it. Academics tend to concern themselves with more timeless but obscure concepts (whose value often takes decades to be appreciated by the industry).

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis not quite. This one prof was obsessed with theoretical correctness. Whether OOP or whatever doesn't matter (OOP was hot at the time, everyone and his uncle were doing it for the hipness factor alone). I was pointing out theoretical correctness vs. pragmatism, not using one methodology over another.We ended up building pipelines around the slowest parts of the monstrosity to shortcut some time sensitive things, while leaving the bulk in place.

Comment: Moreover, expect senior engineers to be wary of [fads](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168089/why-has-extreme-programming-xp-gone-out-of-date-in-favor-of-agile-kanban-etc).

Comment: @JohnWu indeed. Personally I'd rather wait a while before adopting something new, let others take the pains and cost of being an early adopter. Seen enough projects needing major rewrites because some overhyped library collapsed that they depended on.

Comment: "It was a fantastic piece of software design. Sadly, in production and maintenance, it was a nightmare as a result." The second part means the first is untrue. Good design by definition makes software better. If the theory doesn't actually work, the theory is just wrong and following it is a terrible idea.

Comment: Latest greatest tech is fine in theory, until a couple of years down the line when it is no longer supported, or you just can't find anyone to touch it with a barge pole.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis In my experience, that's true the higher up in education you get, like at postgraduate level. But the first year or two of bachelor's classes are absolutely obsessed with rudimentary concepts like OOP. Just look at the AP tests. (AP is college material in high school, if you're not familiar with it.)

Comment: @jpmc26 it was fantastic, when considered purely theoretically, in that it followed all the rules as set out in the standard works about OO design to perfection. Which resulted in a monstrosity that was so unwieldy in its implementation that it was next to useless.

Comment: in my 15 year Software Development career, working on multiple projects for several companies I can say that my pragmatic approach has served me much better than "trying to push for better processes". Allthough all companies have different opinions, being able to listen as a developer is more important than being able to push your ideas.

Comment: I very much agree with this answer in general, though I'm not convinced it really applies to _this_ question. While it's certainly true that implementing a shitton of weekly meetings will not be the best course for _every_ team, it's more likely to be useful than chucking a bunch of design patterns into a codebase for academic/theoretical reasons. So I don't think it's really a fair comparison. OP reports no testing, no proper version control, no well-defined roles... that's a different beast. Your conclusion seems to apply regardless, but that's a relatively small proportion of your answer.

Comment: @Kain0_0 Then again, if you only practice without theoretical knowledge in your nice little bubble, you might easily generate legacy monsters of bad coding with no usage of any proper underlying concepts either, so the next guy will have to completely rewrite it to fit his personal "practical approach". Not to mention, one easily goes for the "natural" algorithm that first comes to mind if one doesn't have any theoretical foundation, thus resulting in craptastic slow code. In other words, it's two sides of a coin. Both can be overdone and to be really good you need a bit of both.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard I agree and want to add "not because it was especially brittle but because it was so complex nobody dared touch it in fear of what would happen" this means it was brittle. Furthermore, implies there were no tests which would give the developers more confidence for making changes. It's trying to push the wrong conclusions - if the design doesn't work in the real world, it's not a problem with software principles in general but their misapplication. In this case, it wasn't a "fantastic design", it was a poor one. If anything, means we should use more theory, not less.

Comment: How can a piece of software do everything according to standards and still be hard to maintain? The whole goal of OO is to create readable and maintainable code. Sounds like your guy was one of those 'brilliant OO theoreticians' that overengineers things because he misunderstands the purpose of OO.

Comment: I'm not sure the anecdote about the high and mighty but ultimately failible architect vs. the plucky band of down-to-earth battle hardened developers is really helping prove your point. To me, the issue seems to be a very poor hand-over: the team tasked with maintaining the system didn't take part in building it, didn't understand the design, lacked the domain knowledge and the expertise to refactor it. Your implication that "loose coupling and all that" are useless, ungrounded academic concepts is really far fetched. I think your main point is valid, but there is too much hyperbole around it.

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. Your anecdote has almost nothing to do with what OP is asking about. You're talking about an apparently elegant solution that lacked a concern for many standard software practices -- workable complexity, maintainability, performance -- and evidently wasn't support by good development practices either. OP's question is about trying to introduce focus on precisely those standard practices as a junior developer, nothing to do with "theory vs. practice."

Comment: @kevin: If "the whole goal of OO is to create readable and maintainable code", then why is it that every piece of OO code I've had to work with has been an indecipherable and unmaintainable mess?  And often enough, slow and memory-intensive to boot, which matters when run times stretch to days and weeks.

Comment: "Several hundred object instantiations and method calls" is most likely 1000x faster than a single simple database query. I don't understand your point here at all.

Comment: @Darkwing I do not see how I implied that theoretical knowledge should be thrown out. I merely agreed that all the best knowledge in the world won't tell you how to implement. You still need to learn how to do that change (read my answer below where i go at length about how to learn how to change things). So I do agree with you that both practice and theory are required, the junior dev here obviously has the theoretical, the advice they need is on the practical edge which can only really be obtained by learning how to negotiate the change into their team while maintaining what already exists.

Comment: I've seen examples like yours as well, and your example is sound, but I find it a bit unfortunate that this answer is voted so high, essentially telling OP to stay down. He is asking "try and push for the above as time goes on" which tells us that he is not jumping in head-over-heels. Also, the points he identified are far from what you are describing; they are not foolish or "modern nonsense", or over-architecting, or applying the newest framework from around the block just for its own sake. I would lick my fingers for having youngsters from uni noticing these things and rooting for change...

Comment: @CarlLeth but 1000x as hard to understand

Comment: "Several hundred object instantiations and method calls" are a piece of cake for a modern CPU. People overthink, letting the architect do this alone without discussions / reviews is a management mistake. OO is about achieving readability and maintainability by reusing concepts, not about using every pattern out there. I have been in the opposite situation: "Experienced" developers without any OO knowledge building a 30K LOC application using static methods and global variables to pass things around, because this is simple and understood by everyone. Good luck maintaining that.

Comment: Look up "Chesterton's Fence" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Chesterton%27s_fence

Comment: Very true. A Computer Science degree program does not and was never intended to teach *any* commercially valuable skill.

Comment: @jwenting. OO should bring an elegance and simplicity to the design. If it doesn't, that is bad OO design. The OO has to be architected for change, allowing an experienced developer to change classes without breaking the whole structure.

Comment: @TKK the depth of knowledge of proper computer scientists **is** commercially valuable. Much more than "self-taught programmers" who think algorithms, complexity theory and formal languages are useless concepts and have no clue about them.

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev now, yes. 20+ years ago, running on 486s and early Pentiums, not so much. The system had a batch print run that needed 48 HOURS to generate a few dozen single page form letters. Shortcutting most of the layers reduced that down to mere minutes.

Comment: vaguely related: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/25/getting-things-done-when-youre-only-a-grunt/

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto That's not what most self-taught programmers think.

Comment: @TKK good to know. Then I wonder why people [keep asking](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/) how to "parse" a context-free language using a regular language. They should know about basic stuff like the pumping lemma, otherwise it's better _not_ to know how they handle user input validation in their websites.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Probably the same reason guys with degrees casually claim they're going to solve NP Hard problems over the weekend, then get mad when I tell them they're not. :)

Comment: @TKK :-O ... degrees in humanities, I hope.

Answer (score 42):

**Yes** *but with a lot of care!*

**Let me clarify that.**

You should strive to improve the habitability of the software. If you look at the code/team/business/project/management and your first response is to take a shower, then it is not habitable. If your first response is to shout yeah!... and then complain when you are turfed out of the office, then you need to make your home more habitable. Its a feeling, and you will know it.

That being said, you are working in a complicated [symathesis](https://norabateson.wordpress.com/2015/11/03/symmathesy-a-word-in-progress/). Anything you do do is likely to go wrong, and probably will make things worse at least in the short term, because a simple change has ripples. So first off become humble, I don't mean become a push over or accept that things must be bad, I mean come to terms with the fact that your good intentions are going to turn on you viciously.

**The Problem**

With the best of intentions you might feel that a broad sweeping change needs to happen, and I don't disagree that these situations do exist, but take a moment to think about it. The current system is working, you and your team are producing code, perhaps its slow, perhaps its painful, but it is working and all of you have experience on how to do this. You know roughly what to expect, in short you are practiced professionals in this system.

After the sweeping change though no one, except perhaps the implementer, knows what to expect. In short everyone has been reset to a neophyte level in this part of the system. That's not good. Neophytes have to learn the new rules which takes time. In that time neophytes are making mistakes because they aren't practiced. Those mistakes become part of the system, which you now have to live with and its no where near as sparkly now.

**A Way Forward**

There are times when slash, burn, and rebuild is by far the best you can do. Its particularly attractive if no one is practiced in the old system, because the only thing being lost is the codified knowledge. If this knowledge is thoroughly incomprehensible then its already lost, and starting over is the only choice. Conversely if the method of codification, or how it used is problematic but functioning, that knowledge is still accessible, and perhaps its worth keeping, perhaps its not - Just don't take the decision lightly.

The other choice is to work with the system so that everyone has a frame of reference, but to change small parts of the system so that everyone on the team is aware, or if they are not aware of the change, it is both easy to notice and easy to learn. This is the basis for the practices called [Kaizen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaizen). A more developer orientated formula is presented in the presentation Shaving the Golden Yak, I highly recommend watching it and thinking it through.

So find a small thing that can be changed that will improve your life, and hopefully those of a few others. Fix or improve the situation. This will give you practice and experience on putting changes into practice. Make sure you get feedback: could you have discussed it better, was it actually useful, did it upset another part of the system. Develop your feel for what can be done and how to do it.

Now three things have happened:

- you have improved the system,
- you have obtained experience on how to change the system
- the team has seen you successfully change the system.

Now pick another thing to improve, as your experience grows and as you eliminate low hanging problems you will start to confront the harder issues in the system but at least now when you say we have to change X:

- You know how the change will affect the system
- You know what problems it will generate (what rules need relearning)
- You know some immediate ways to fix, or improve issues the change will introduce
- the people around you are aware that you are knowledgeable of the system, and capable of changing it successfully

Comment: Lots to agree with there.  One thing worth stressing is that no codebase or procedure is perfect; everything is always a compromise.  And much as you might want to chuck everything away and start again, as you say, IME it's usually far better to evolve slowly, by small steps.  That way you can bring everyone along with you, and avoid losing existing knowledge.  The important thing is knowing where you want to get to; that way, you can spot and take the opportunities as they arise.

Comment: @gidds I think that was my point, its best to make small changes that everyone is aware of, or at least is obvious to them has changed, and easily read. While i do believe its important to have a long-term goal in mind to help you pick and choose between all the ways you could improve things, I don't think its always possible to formulate one, particularly for junior developers with limited experience in working at scale with people. Formulating improvements to the status quo is much easier. does this irritate you? *Yes* What is something small you can do to improve the situation?

Comment: @gidds reading your comment again, I agree no one procedure or process is perfect, or even applicable to a given situation, and if miss handled can even take the team to a place worse than never having tried. That being said, even when successful the end result is usually a compromise between all of the competing requirements that the software and its team somehow have to satisfy. That is a lot harder if the business is in a regulated industry. Governments are not fond of rule breakers.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you can. But you have to be careful.

At the start of my career (a very long time ago) I was lucky/unlucky to get into a few months old project as the "junior".

I immediately noticed that there was (OMG) no code repository! All code merges were done manually by sending zip files to each other by mail.

So I went to my (also new) manager and suggested that we should have a repository. The answer was: "OK, organize it".

So organizing a code repository, without help, and being new in the company, was a humbling experience.

When I set it all up, (shock), nobody wanted to use it. So I tried to push things along and luckily my manager understood its importance so I had support.

But this resulted in me not being well liked.

---

My advice is to first feel out your team members. What they think is important to set up the next step.

Maybe they also have a list like yours. Maybe they have thought everything through and they wanted to do that "thing" on the list.

The whole team has to be aligned.

But if they are not, then you can still work professionally. And find like minded people and work together how you think it should be done. If this brings good results, then more people will work with you, eventually it will become "the" process.

Just like with code, the same for development processes: continuous improvement is needed.

So yes, you should always try to improve that which is possible to improve.

But also remember that many people you are working with could also be professionals, and that they know what is wrong and what is needed.

Comment: It sounds to me like you went behind people's backs without justifying anything to your fellow developers first, just having a manager force it through. Nobody likes "that guy." So yeah, if you have suggestions for improvements, bring them up with your colleagues, but most importantly: be able to justify your suggestions to them. Why will it make things better? How will it save people time and effort? Are there any drawbacks to the new way? Etc. If you can predict and prepare responses to people's concerns, they'll be much more likely to accept your suggestions willingly rather than by force.

Comment: I didn't feel as if it "went behind people's backs". I reported the issue to my manager, he told me to take care of it, and I did.

Answer (score 14):

> Is it worth a (junior) developer's effort to try and push for the above as time goes on?

Yes, it is always worth your effort to try and make things better. You know best what problems you face after all.

But as you mention, there are lots of problems to solve and many of those problems are not terribly valuable. And at a lot of places, there will be insurmountable barriers to your success or other people who are far better positioned to champion them. So you should always try to make things better, even if that means picking *which* things you spend your time trying to make better.

Because in the end, if you're not part of the solution you are part of the problem.

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/38244

Answer (score 14):

Yes. But organizational change is hard even for a senior so if you really want to make a difference do it in the right way:

- **Not during the first weeks:** Use this time to:

  - Create a good first impresion. Show that you fit in the team.
  - Understantand the culture and politics or your company. Is it safe to push for changes?
  - Build a good relationship with coworkers
  - Learn about the process, rules and needs of your team
  - Learn your work and do it the best you can. You will surely be busy enough.
- **Choose your battles. Get some early victories**: You may arrive with energy to change everything but this is unrealistic. Focus on some low hanging fruit and show that your ideas work. You want them to be receptive to more complex improvements. And remember that things are easier in books.
- **Consider the implication to others**: I do refactors affecting lots of files. Even if they improve the code I must be very carefull to avoid turning the merges into a pain in the ass. Try also to undertand the reasons why they keep working like that. May be they can't use Scrum as they lack tests and the are, understandably, afraid to push untested code to production frequently. Writing a realiable test is no easy task. The current code could be really hard to test. Furthermore, the team may not used neither to write tests or testeable code. The current code base may specially hard to test and needs to be refactored. It may require years to change this problem but at least you can focus on the root cause.
- **Do not judge. Do not demand. Ask for it and listen carefully:** This is a moment when communication is critical and we, the programmers, are usually not very good at subtle nuances. [There are techniques to help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4wH-BI2YeX4&t=0s&list=PLEx5khR4g7PJquVHXtkcdo-QzK54bfmY9&index=13). It is easy to keep pushing for our idea instead of focusing on the answer. First make sure that they feel that you have got their points. Understand that feelings are important. What does this change makes them feel? fear? insuficiency? anger? frustration? hope? Lazy? Stupid? (Never make people feel stupid). Of course you would have asked a lot of questions before and this will prevent a lot of false steps.
- **Lead by the example**: complaining is easy, creating the change is hard. Show  results and people will believe you. If they do not use test you can write your unit tests. If people do not document you can share some google docs with the team.  Understand that "Ok, do it" is one of the best possible scenarios and then you need to deliver. In this case **you need to have thought what resources you are going to need**. Example: give me a small Amazon instance and two hours from the admins for a Jenkins server
- **Keep It Small and Simple (and Cheap):** You do not want to wait for a formal budget approval or have your bosses think that you are lossing valuable time from expensive programmers. It would be great to have this code review sofware or evaluate several open source tools but we will just use the repo for the moment.
- **Get critical mass:** Gather the group of people focused on improving quality. You can even go with them to conferences and ask for help or mentoring. [Peopleware](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321934113) describe the "waking the giant phenomenon" in with the base of the team literally rebels against some stupid practices that slow productivity. This individually would have been really dangerous and I would not have recomend. But if all the group agrees change is easier.
- **Give it some time. Afterwards vote with your feets:** You may want to try it during a few months up to two years. But some companies do not have easy solutions. Some teams do not want to change and do not have incentives. And some code bases are pure horror. If you feel that it is you against the world remember that there are plenty of offers in job pool. You want to learn good practices and in the long run you will be better in a pleace with sligtly less wage but getting experience that will make you more valuable.

**Bonus: If you succeed write it down for your CV/Interviews.** As a Junior you usually have very little to say and creating a change for better is always a great sign. You want to have a very clear and realistic view about what you personally did and what was work from others. Imagine the following interview question.

- Tell me about a time in which you made a difference in the team.
- Well, I was  in a place were they had very old fashioned practices. A
  lot of people was't happy with it and productivity had a big room to improve. So I proposed to make a fast experiment with retrospectives, we did X, and Y and the as a result we had this wonderfull measureable result".

Comment: “Not during the first weeks” I think especially during the first few weeks simply asking questions can achieve a lot. Not only will you learn about the project and work flow, you’ll also make your colleagues think about why X is in Y and not in Z, missing documentation, cumbersome tools (why do I need 20 commands to integrate my change?) etc

Comment: I may have stated it badly: Of course you sould ask questions on other moments and specially during the first days. My intended but may by midcommunicated point is that as a Junior you do not "PUSH FOR CHANGES" the first days as you may be be seem a know-it-all arrogant and you lack tools for something so difficutl as changing an organization

Answer (score 9):

Yes. But not the things you suggest.

Out of your list Unit/Integration tests are the only item you can make progress on.

You can start adding these by yourself with minimal time investment and show instant value. Its a technical problem with widely accepted benefits and wont affect others work practices. While also gaining you mdore knowledge of the code base even if the results arent accepted. An easy sell.

The others are generally business processes that involve the entire team or even other teams. You could suggest improvements, but they will be hard for a junior employee to change and the process of changing them is generally non techincal and probably unrelated to your normal work.

I would also suggest things like, setting up CI pipelines, automated deployments, versioning, packaging libraries as good stuff to attack

Comment: As a junior employee I proposed all of these. Over a number of years, with some assistance (and lots of buy-in) I then successfully implemented them. By the end I was the senior architect. It can work, and it's often worth trying. ;) However you have to pick your battles and know when you're facing an uphill struggle for something that may not even fit the profile/dynamic of the organisation very well. In another role I was tempted to go down the same route, and decided not to even broach the topic because _there_ it would never have worked out and wasn't particularly important either.

Comment: Unit test and continuous integration are a good choice to start. They will give you the best return on investment. Do not try Scrum without the technical practices that allow it to work. How can you have frequent deployments if every one is dangerous and needs a lot of work from testers and sysadmins?

Comment: Unit tests/integration tests are not necessarily something one can immediately start implementing due to architecture.  Furthermore, they tend to force certain patterns which can go against the existing order of things.  While they do have value, it's not always an easy home run as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on:

- how much you expect to get from better practices
- how much effort you'll have to spend getting there
- what are the chance of success and risks - from simple adoption failure to new practices are actually terrible, code quality degrades, key people leave, everyone hates you and you got to find another job in a different city where nobody knows your name

Basically: it's well within your responsibilities to spend some reasonable time advocating for what you think is best - but the decision should be a team or management responsibility. Keep in mind that alienating people is rarely worth it, even if you end up with better practices.

Answer (score 1):

Don't start with the most complicated things like Scrum. Start with the easiest steps possible.

You did not mention source code management. Do you have some source code repository (git, svn, cvs, ...)? A strategy for tagging and branching? Those are simple steps a beginner can do. Read up what problems these steps (try to) solve, and how that helps your company reduce costs (that's what management is interested in).

Next step could be automated builds, nightly or directly after every check in, e.g. with Jenkins. You can also run tests automatically. And add some tools for measuring code quality (oh yes: defining some coding standards is also a good step).

As for scrum, better read about "Extreme Programming" (XP). Scrum is based on many ideas of XP and adds a formalized process around them - the concepts of XP can still be used without that process.

Suggest things, provide back ground information, try to convince others to try it, analyze the results, ... but don't expect to much co-operation from others: most people prefer to stick with their old bad habits. But when you don't try that, nothing will improve.

Answer (score 1):

#### In the beginning, ask questions

Reading your list, I would suggest the following questions (refer back to your list to see how they fit):

- How do I see what work the business owners are requesting?
- Have you tried [Scrum]?
- Who's the product owner for this?
- What roles are there?
- What does [this role] do?
- What role is responsible for [this activity]?
- Have you tried a daily standup?
- How do I communicate my impediments to the rest of the team?
- How do I find out on what other members of the team are working?
- Should we put [this] in the issue tracking tool?
- How should we write [this] in the issue tracking tool?
- When [this] happens, should we put it in the issue tracking tool as [that]?
- How do we test?
- How do we record our tests for others to reuse?
- Have you tried [JUnit]?
- Where is [this] documented?
- Have you tried [MediaWiki]?

Replace things in [brackets] as appropriate to make the questions make sense or fit your priorities.  Consider rewording if my wording doesn't match your style.

You may have already started doing that.  Favor one-on-one conversations over group conversations.  Because one-on-one, you can get a better read of what the other person thinks.  Is that person for this change?  Against it?  Weakly?  Rabidly?

When you're new, asking questions is practically free.  People should expect you to ask questions.  Even if your questions implicitly advocate a position that they oppose, they shouldn't get angry.  They should explain why they oppose that position.  I recommend against arguing with them.  Arguing tends to harden positions more than it convinces.  Note who has what position and move on.

#### Later, take steps

Look for ways that you and possibly others (i.e. those you noted agreeing with you previously) can start the changes you want.  Not everyone wants a standup?  Why not?  Perhaps those of you who want one can have your own standup.  Not as effective as with the whole team, but more than you have now.

When you have an impediment (and assuming you can't share in a standup), email the team for help.

Identify what the roles should be, possibly with the support of others who agree with you.  Start consistently going to people when work involves the role you (possibly a group you) think that they should have.  If they push back, ask them to identify who should own that role.

Ask product owners (that you identified) to write up descriptions of how they think their product should work now and in the future.

Install a test framework (if others favor this, make a joint decision on which framework) and use it for your projects.  When you're fixing bugs, write tests.  Document this in the bug report on the issue tracker (wrote test demonstrating bug, stored at [location]).  Encourage others to run the tests when they make changes.  If they don't, run the tests yourself and submit issues to the tracker as necessary.

If you can get management support, install wiki software or similar and start documenting your stuff.  If people ask you questions that show they didn't read the documentation, point them at the relevant pages.  Encourage them to ask more questions if they don't understand the documentation.  If they continue asking questions covered in the documentation, quote from the documentation when answering.  Consider encouraging them to update the wiki if you think that the problem was structural rather than them not reading.

I would suggest only concentrating on one task at a time.  And certainly only push one at a time.  Don't push hard.  See [this example](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/385162/236539) of pushing harder than the group wanted.  Concentrate more on changing your behavior than theirs.  If your way is the right way, that should be obvious to people observing you.  Actions speak louder than words.  Try not to repeat yourself with the same person when you do nudge.  Once you've led the horse to water, leave the choice of when or whether to drink to the other.

#### Eventually, you'll be senior

Over time, your team will hire new people.  You'll stop being the new hire and be able to advocate your positions with new people.  Work with them to make changes.  And you may find that you are making progress with your existing teammates as well.  Or if that's not working, look for a new job where they have better practices.  There's no real hurry.  You have a job.  You can wait a while on having a better job, either by improving that one or finding a better one.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: No, for all the reasons outlined in the other answers. Even when being a middle or senior dev, it's usually better to **seek first to understand** when joining a new team.

**A proposed solution**:

1) whenever you see something you feel should be improved, take note of it! (in a notebook, in a digital note...)

2) After 6 month, go back to your notes and check them. How many ideas now feel pointless and inadequate? Most likely a lot, you saved yourself some embarrassment. If some ideas still hold, now would be a good time to introduce them, if possible by testing them yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

You said the team is quite new (3 years old), so if you can not introduce some good principles now, it will be harder  do that 10 years after. Some of the things you mentioned such as testing and versioning system are among the ones you could suggest already, but do not throw the suggestion just like that without emphasizing on their  obvious benefits and picking the tools your development stack requires.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, and agree lots of good content in the other answers.

I think it needs called out that a key issue here is not the specific practices, but overall team culture.

- Creating cultural change is *hard*.
- More so if you seen as "junior"

Everything else can follow if there is a means of achieving **continuous improvement**.

My approach to achieving that is:

- Documented processes and procedures
- Retrospectives with the team whose actions are changes to the process documentation.

I guess if you do not have sprints you do not yet have regular retros. All you do need is a conversation with the team, and then action that.

**You** can easily start documenting processes. "I am the new guy, have I got this right? Let me write that down." It is important to then actually follow the process yourself, or try to and call our where it breaks.

Maybe you start with such conversations being *ad hoc* and then suggest regular rituals.

Taking this approach allows an incremental, softly softly, approach. You can avoid appearing as a junior who things they know it all and instead try to be a facilitator for the team making change.

Some considerations:

- Some teams have a poor process but actually already know that. They
  want to change and just need something to catalyse that. Other teams
  really stuck in their ways and a lot harder to change.
- Same goes for individuals.
- You need to be sensitive to that and figure out who on the team is
  open to change and who is not. Understand why.
- Find easy wins.
- Make the changes welcome to the team: Find their individual pain
  points and try to help fix them.

Answer (score 0):

"Worth it" depends on what you want (technical vs. organizational "wins"), whether and how you will be rewarded, how persistent you are willing to be, your sensitivity to your own or co-workers' perception of "failure", how long you plan on staying, and how much you like the company mission and your co-workers. Remember that in any given hour of a lumberjack's life, he is either cutting trees or he is sharpening his saw so that his work is easier.